# $location.search is not updated imediatly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-routing

I have a problem that my url doesn't get updated every time i set it. It is somehow connected with the directive, because in other cases it works.

So my question is, on what is the `$location.search('dd', val)` depended on, what is it waiting for, because function gets called, but the url is not updated.

Answer (score 2):

it waits for a digest..

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   $location.search('dd', val)
})
```

Comment: is there a way, to detect, what is making the digest cycle to take so long?

Comment: angular batarang has a performance tab - https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang#performance

Answer (score 1):

Digest cycle takes time to update the DOM.
I had similar issue where I had to reload the page after updating the url.

I used $timeout with code that is required to run after completing the digest cycle.

```
$location.search('filter', null);

$timeout(function() {
   //the code which needs to run after dom rendering
   $window.location.reload();
}.bind(this))
```