# Angularjs $location is not triggered the first time and uses old values the next time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I use **angular-ui slider** to select a desired range:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init="sizeRange.val = [10, 80]">
    <div ui-slider="sizeRange.options"
        min="10" max="80" step="5"
        ng-model="sizeRange.val"></div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="sizeRange.val[0]">
    <input type="number" ng-model="sizeRange.val[1]">
</div>
```

When user moves the slider to the desired number and stops, the following function is triggered that appends the selected range to URL query string:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.sizeRange= {
        'options': {
            range: true,
            stop: function (event, ui) { $scope.filterUpdate($scope.sizeRange.val); }
        }
    };

    $scope.filterUpdate = function (size) {
        console.log(size);
        $location.search({"sizeRange": size});
    };
}
```

So when I move the slider the first time, the `$location.search()` is not triggered and no URL string is appended, however the function itself seems to be called successfully, because I can see the log and correct selected values in my console called from within the function. When I move the slider the second time, the URL string is now appended, but it contains old data from the first time I moved the slider. So every time I move it, the `$location.search()` updates URL string with data from previous move.

What can be interfering with the `$location.search()` to prevent it to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$location.search() or $location.url() functions don't always trigger on the current $digest cycle.  You can either do -

```
$timeout(function() {
  $location.search({"sizeRange": size});
});
```

Another thread talking about the same problem - [$location.search is not updated imediatly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572613/location-search-is-not-updated-imediatly)

Answer (score 0):

`sizeRange.val` change might not be there as soon as the stop event is triggered. You may check whether the value is available in the ui object? If it is not, you can wrap your function in $timeout so it runs on the next iteration.

```
stop: function (event, ui) { 
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.filterUpdate($scope.sizeRange.val);
    } 
}
```